# Img element is being selected instead of the parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't know why because it works in my other tool bar section but when I check for which element I'm clicking it selects the image rather than the div, which it doesn't on the main toolbar section.

I was able to fix it by adding a pointer-events: none; to the image's CSS but it was a hacky way of doing it and I still have no idea what's causing it.

Thanks in advance!

```js
var pointer_tool_on = true;
var ruler_tool_on = false;
var draw_tool_on = false;
var draw_tool_freehand = true;
var draw_tool_polyline = false;
var draw_tool_circledraw = false;
var draw_tool_squaredraw = false;
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log(e.target.id);
  switch (e.target.id) {
    case "ruler_id":
      false_all_tools();
      ruler_tool_on = true;
      set_class_tool();
      break;
    case "cursor_tool_id":
      false_all_tools();
      pointer_tool_on = true;
      set_class_tool();
      break;
    case "draw_id":
      false_all_tools();
      draw_tool_on = true;
      set_class_tool();
      break;
    case "del_id":
      clear_canvas();
      break;
    case "freehand":
      document.getElementById("draw_id").src = "../VTT/images/1024px-Circle_-_black_simple.svg.png";
      console.log(e.target.id);
      break;
  }
  return;
});

function false_all_tools() {
  pointer_tool_on = false;
  ruler_tool_on = false;
  draw_tool_on = false;
}

function false_all_tools_sublist() {
  var draw_tool_freehand = false;
  var draw_tool_polyline = false;
  var draw_tool_circledraw = false;
  var draw_tool_squaredraw = false;
}

function set_class_tool() {
  if (ruler_tool_on == true) {
    document.getElementById("ruler_id").setAttribute('class', "elemI2");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ruler_id").setAttribute('class', "elemI");
  }
  if (pointer_tool_on == true) {
    document.getElementById("cursor_tool_id").setAttribute('class', "elemI2");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("cursor_tool_id").setAttribute('class', "elemI");
  }
  if (draw_tool_on == true) {
    document.getElementById("draw_id").setAttribute('class', "elemI2");
    document.getElementById("color_picker_width").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("draw_sub_list").style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("draw_id").setAttribute('class', "elemI");
    document.getElementById("color_picker_width").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("draw_sub_list").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
set_class_tool();
```

```css
#tool-panel {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #484848;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 55px;
  right: 370px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #808080;
  user-select: none;
}

.elem {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.elemI {
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.elemI:hover {
  background-color: #606060;
  opacity: 1;
}

.elemI2 {
  background-color: #606060;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

#color_picker_width {
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #484848;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #808080;
  top: 10px;
  right: 370px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#draw_sub_list {
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #484848;
  right: 50px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #808080;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 2px;
}

.draw_sub_list_class {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  opacity: 0.5;
  object-fit: contain;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.draw_sub_list_class:hover {
  background-color: #606060;
  opacity: 1;
}

.draw_list_img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tool-panel">
  <div id="cursor-tool" class="elem">
    <img id="cursor_tool_id" class="elemI" src="../VTT/images/cursor_PNG78.png"></img>
  </div>
  <div id="ruler" class="elem">
    <img id="ruler_id" class="elemI" src="../VTT/images/ruler_PNG78.png"></img>
  </div>
  <div id="draw" class="elem">
    <div id="color_picker_width">
      <input id="color_picker" type="color"></input>
      <input id="color_picker2" type="color"></input>
      <input id="width" type="number" placeholder="Line width"></input>
    </div>
    <img id="draw_id" class="elemI" src="../VTT/images/paint-brush-4127172_960_720.png"></img>
    <div id="draw_sub_list">
      <div id="freehand" class="draw_sub_list_class">
        <img class="draw_list_img" src="../VTT/images/paint-brush-4127172_960_720.png"></img>
        Freehand
      </div>
      <div id="polyline" class="draw_sub_list_class">
        <img class="draw_list_img" src="../VTT/images/194972-200.png"></img>
        Polygon Line
      </div>
      <div id="circle_draw" class="draw_sub_list_class">
        <img class="draw_list_img" src="../VTT/images/1024px-Circle_-_black_simple.svg.png"></img>
        Circle
      </div>
      <div id="square_draw" class="draw_sub_list_class">
        <img class="draw_list_img" src="../VTT/images/Square_-_black_simple.svg.png"></img>
        Square
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="del" class="elem">
    <img id="del_id" class="elemI" src="../VTT/images/trash+bin+icon-1320086460670911435.png"></img>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `e.target` is the element you clicked on. If you click on the image, it will be the image.

Comment: @skara9 I don't think that will work. `this` will be the element that the listener was added to, which is `document`.

Comment: @Barmar ah never mind then, just took a quick glance and missed that

Comment: @Barmar Do you know why it selects the Div on the main toolbar instead of the image is it because its the entire div's area or something?

Comment: Which is the main toolbar? But it probably depends on whether the image covers the whole div. If you click on the div outside the image, you'll get the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your listener is for handling clicks to those specific `div`s, just set it as such with

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.elem').forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener('click', elemClick));
```

and for your `elemClick` handler function, you can access the clicked div with `this`

```js
function elemClick() {
  console.log(this.id);
  switch(this.id) {
    ...
```

```js
var pointer_tool_on = true;
var ruler_tool_on = false;
var draw_tool_on = false;
var draw_tool_freehand = true;
var draw_tool_polyline = false;
var draw_tool_circledraw = false;
var draw_tool_squaredraw = false;
function elemClick() {
  console.log(this.id);
  switch (this.id) {
    case "ruler_id":
      false_all_tools();
      ruler_tool_on = true;
      set_class_tool();
      break;
    case "cursor_tool_id":
      false_all_tools();
      pointer_tool_on = true;
      set_class_tool();
      break;
    case "draw_id":
      false_all_tools();
      draw_tool_on = true;
      set_class_tool();
      break;
    case "del_id":
      clear_canvas();
      break;
    case "freehand":
      document.getElementById("draw_id").src = "../VTT/images/1024px-Circle_-_black_simple.svg.png";
      console.log(e.target.id);
      break;
  }
  return;
}

document.querySelectorAll('.elem').forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener('click', elemClick));

function false_all_tools() {
  pointer_tool_on = false;
  ruler_tool_on = false;
  draw_tool_on = false;
}

function false_all_tools_sublist() {
  var draw_tool_freehand = false;
  var draw_tool_polyline = false;
  var draw_tool_circledraw = false;
  var draw_tool_squaredraw = false;
}

function set_class_tool() {
  if (ruler_tool_on == true) {
    document.getElementById("ruler_id").setAttribute('class', "elemI2");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ruler_id").setAttribute('class', "elemI");
  }
  if (pointer_tool_on == true) {
    document.getElementById("cursor_tool_id").setAttribute('class', "elemI2");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("cursor_tool_id").setAttribute('class', "elemI");
  }
  if (draw_tool_on == true) {
    document.getElementById("draw_id").setAttribute('class', "elemI2");
    document.getElementById("color_picker_width").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("draw_sub_list").style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("draw_id").setAttribute('class', "elemI");
    document.getElementById("color_picker_width").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("draw_sub_list").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
set_class_tool();
```

```css
#tool-panel {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #484848;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 55px;
  right: 370px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #808080;
  user-select: none;
}

.elem {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.elemI {
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.elemI:hover {
  background-color: #606060;
  opacity: 1;
}

.elemI2 {
  background-color: #606060;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

#color_picker_width {
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #484848;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #808080;
  top: 10px;
  right: 370px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#draw_sub_list {
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #484848;
  right: 50px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #808080;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 2px;
}

.draw_sub_list_class {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  opacity: 0.5;
  object-fit: contain;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.draw_sub_list_class:hover {
  background-color: #606060;
  opacity: 1;
}

.draw_list_img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tool-panel">
  <div id="cursor-tool" class="elem">
    <img id="cursor_tool_id" class="elemI" src="../VTT/images/cursor_PNG78.png"></img>
  </div>
  <div id="ruler" class="elem">
    <img id="ruler_id" class="elemI" src="../VTT/images/ruler_PNG78.png"></img>
  </div>
  <div id="draw" class="elem">
    <div id="color_picker_width">
      <input id="color_picker" type="color"></input>
      <input id="color_picker2" type="color"></input>
      <input id="width" type="number" placeholder="Line width"></input>
    </div>
    <img id="draw_id" class="elemI" src="../VTT/images/paint-brush-4127172_960_720.png"></img>
    <div id="draw_sub_list">
      <div id="freehand" class="draw_sub_list_class">
        <img class="draw_list_img" src="../VTT/images/paint-brush-4127172_960_720.png"></img>
        Freehand
      </div>
      <div id="polyline" class="draw_sub_list_class">
        <img class="draw_list_img" src="../VTT/images/194972-200.png"></img>
        Polygon Line
      </div>
      <div id="circle_draw" class="draw_sub_list_class">
        <img class="draw_list_img" src="../VTT/images/1024px-Circle_-_black_simple.svg.png"></img>
        Circle
      </div>
      <div id="square_draw" class="draw_sub_list_class">
        <img class="draw_list_img" src="../VTT/images/Square_-_black_simple.svg.png"></img>
        Square
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="del" class="elem">
    <img id="del_id" class="elemI" src="../VTT/images/trash+bin+icon-1320086460670911435.png"></img>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`e.target` is the most deeply nested element that you clicked on.

If you want to get something intermediate, you need to add the event listener to the elements directly, and then use `e.currentTarget` to get the element that the listener was bound to.

```js
var pointer_tool_on = true;
var ruler_tool_on = false;
var draw_tool_on = false;
var draw_tool_freehand = true;
var draw_tool_polyline = false;
var draw_tool_circledraw = false;
var draw_tool_squaredraw = false;
document.querySelectorAll(".elem").forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.id);
  switch (e.currentTarget.id) {
    case "ruler":
      false_all_tools();
      ruler_tool_on = true;
      set_class_tool();
      break;
    case "cursor-tool":
      false_all_tools();
      pointer_tool_on = true;
      set_class_tool();
      break;
    case "draw":
      false_all_tools();
      draw_tool_on = true;
      set_class_tool();
      break;
    case "del":
      clear_canvas();
      break;
    case "freehand":
      document.getElementById("draw_id").src = "../VTT/images/1024px-Circle_-_black_simple.svg.png";
      console.log(e.target.id);
      break;
  }
  return;
}));

function false_all_tools() {
  pointer_tool_on = false;
  ruler_tool_on = false;
  draw_tool_on = false;
}

function false_all_tools_sublist() {
  var draw_tool_freehand = false;
  var draw_tool_polyline = false;
  var draw_tool_circledraw = false;
  var draw_tool_squaredraw = false;
}

function set_class_tool() {
  if (ruler_tool_on == true) {
    document.getElementById("ruler_id").setAttribute('class', "elemI2");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ruler_id").setAttribute('class', "elemI");
  }
  if (pointer_tool_on == true) {
    document.getElementById("cursor_tool_id").setAttribute('class', "elemI2");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("cursor_tool_id").setAttribute('class', "elemI");
  }
  if (draw_tool_on == true) {
    document.getElementById("draw_id").setAttribute('class', "elemI2");
    document.getElementById("color_picker_width").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("draw_sub_list").style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("draw_id").setAttribute('class', "elemI");
    document.getElementById("color_picker_width").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("draw_sub_list").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
set_class_tool();
```

```css
#tool-panel {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #484848;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 55px;
  right: 370px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #808080;
  user-select: none;
}

.elem {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.elemI {
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.elemI:hover {
  background-color: #606060;
  opacity: 1;
}

.elemI2 {
  background-color: #606060;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

#color_picker_width {
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #484848;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #808080;
  top: 10px;
  right: 370px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#draw_sub_list {
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #484848;
  right: 50px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #808080;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 2px;
}

.draw_sub_list_class {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  opacity: 0.5;
  object-fit: contain;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.draw_sub_list_class:hover {
  background-color: #606060;
  opacity: 1;
}

.draw_list_img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tool-panel">
  <div id="cursor-tool" class="elem">
    <img id="cursor_tool_id" class="elemI" src="../VTT/images/cursor_PNG78.png"></img>
  </div>
  <div id="ruler" class="elem">
    <img id="ruler_id" class="elemI" src="../VTT/images/ruler_PNG78.png"></img>
  </div>
  <div id="draw" class="elem">
    <div id="color_picker_width">
      <input id="color_picker" type="color"></input>
      <input id="color_picker2" type="color"></input>
      <input id="width" type="number" placeholder="Line width"></input>
    </div>
    <img id="draw_id" class="elemI" src="../VTT/images/paint-brush-4127172_960_720.png"></img>
    <div id="draw_sub_list">
      <div id="freehand" class="draw_sub_list_class">
        <img class="draw_list_img" src="../VTT/images/paint-brush-4127172_960_720.png"></img>
        Freehand
      </div>
      <div id="polyline" class="draw_sub_list_class">
        <img class="draw_list_img" src="../VTT/images/194972-200.png"></img>
        Polygon Line
      </div>
      <div id="circle_draw" class="draw_sub_list_class">
        <img class="draw_list_img" src="../VTT/images/1024px-Circle_-_black_simple.svg.png"></img>
        Circle
      </div>
      <div id="square_draw" class="draw_sub_list_class">
        <img class="draw_list_img" src="../VTT/images/Square_-_black_simple.svg.png"></img>
        Square
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="del" class="elem">
    <img id="del_id" class="elemI" src="../VTT/images/trash+bin+icon-1320086460670911435.png"></img>
  </div>
</div>
```